# Exclude dependency from gradleApi()

Tags: gradle

In `build.gradle` I have a dependency to `gradleApi()`:

```
compile gradleApi()
```

However, it adds JAR that breaks my build (duplicated SLF4J binding). How can I exclude some particular dependency from `gradleApi()` (standard `exclude` does not seem to work)? If not possible, what other workarounds do I have?

Comment: Try to use `compileOnly` instead of `compile`.

Comment: I assume you’re writing a Gradle plugin (otherwise why would you use the `gradleApi()` dependency?). I wonder why you’d want to provide your own SLF4J binding. IMHO, that’d be unexpected for users of the Gradle plugin since the plugin should typically log via the logger provided by Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem:

Guess you are writing a gradle plugin and you use gradleApi() dependency.
gradleApi() uses SLF4J internal implementation like @Chriki mentioned in the comment. Your own SFL4J implementation will be ignored.

This problem also arises if SLF4J implementation is being injected through the transitive dependency in your plugin extension. You will get a warning form SLF4J:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:....gradle/caches/../generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-....jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/....gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.25/8dacf9514f0c707cbbcdd6fd699e8940d42fb54e/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext]
```

Discussion on Gradle forum: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/logging-in-gradle-plugin/31685/2

### Solution:

#### Remove cusotm SLF4J implementation

To leave only Gradle Api based logger in the final solution with preventing any transitive SLF4J dependency in the module configuration.

```
configurations {
  implementation.exclude group: 'org.slf4j' // will exclude all transitive dependencies for org.slf4j, or any other specific logger implementation
}

dependencies {
  // No org.slf4j dependencies here
}
```

I have to give creds to [concretepage.com](https://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/gradle-exclude-transitive-dependency-example) where I found the explanation of how you can exclude dependencies in configuration.

#### Customize Gradle logging

More on actual Gradle logging system how to use and extend it form the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html).